# I know I am getting a stackoverflow because I am using recursion but is there an easy way to get round this?

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow

I want to add an image to an ImageButton depending on a number between 0 and 10. My getNumber method is:

```
    public int getNumber(){
    // get a random number between 0 and 10
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    num = randomNumber.nextInt(10);
    return num;
}
```

I want every image to be unique but the problem I was having was that if numList did contain num it just would leave the button blank. I've tried to call permuteButton again recursively until num is not contained within my list but this does not seem to work.

```
    public void  permuteButton(ImageButton btn){    

        getNumber();

        for(int i=0; i<=numList.size(); i++){
            //check if the number is already being used
            if( numList.contains(num) ){
                permuteButton(btn);
            }
            // else the list doesnt have the number so assign the picture and add number to list
            else{
                numList.add(num);
                assignPictures(btn);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm sorry if this is a simple question.

Comment: Don't use recursion - use a stack based solution (collection).

Comment: One minor issue; you need to assign something to your result from `getNumber()`; otherwise, it does nothing.

Comment: Stop sooner... but imo recursion doesn't feel like the most natural solution here.

Comment: I looked at collections but I'm not sure how I could implement those methods in the API to make sure every ImageButton gets an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is similar to the last suggestion from Jon Skeet.

```
// might be more than 10 ImageButtons, with only 10 images
for (ImageButton imageButton : imageButtons)  
   imageButton.putImage(randomImage.next());

...

public class RandomImage {
   private final List<Image> shuffledImages;
   private int currentIndex;

   public RandomImage(List<Image> images) {
      shuffledImages = new ArrayList<>(images.size());
      shuffledImages.addAll(images);
      currentIndex = -1;
   }

   public Image next() {
      currentIndex++;
      if (currentIndex % shuffledImages.size() == 0) {
         currentIndex = 0;
         Collections.shuffle(shuffledImages);
      }
      return shuffledImages[currentIndex];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are various things wrong with this code:

- It would be better to have a single instance of `Random` instead of creating a new instance on each call to `getNumber()`
- Rather than changing an *instance* variable within `getNumber()`, it would be sensible to just return the value and assign that to a *local* variable in `permuteButton`
- Instead of recursion, you *could* use a `while` loop in `permuteButton`:

  ```
  int num = getNumber();
  while (numList.contains(num)) {
      num = getNumber();
  }
  numList.add(num);
  assignPictures(btn); // Presumably you'd now want to pass in num too
  ```
- It would probably be a better idea to just shuffle the list to start with, create a `Queue` from it, then you can just take an item from the queue each time you need one. (This would also make it very easy to spot when you've used them all)

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a while loop and just passed num as a second parameter. Now though the app won't respond but I can see on logcat messages such as ... freed 422K, 6% free. This just goes on and my app doesn't assign any images. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: @ConnorAtherton: Not without seeing more of the code, no. But that sounds like a separate question.

Comment: I have it working now thank you. I used a queue then just used queue.poll() for each separate button and it does randomly add images. Thanks for the inspiration!